# FB new modern dialog missing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I see Facebook updated the sharing dialog.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0

Currently I am using feed dialog and am passing `caption`, `name`, `description`, but seems new share dialog does not have this parameters. Am I missing something ? 
It seems that new share dialog is reading info from og:meta, but with feed I can have multiple share buttons on the same page.